# Alternative to Stackdriver Debugger for Python 3

Tags: debugging, stackdriver

I love [Stackdriver debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/)'s capabilities of debugging production code to see variable state, etc.  But it [only supports python 2.7](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-python/issues/2).  Is there any alternative available (open source or closed) for Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 support has since been added to Stackdriver Debugger. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-python/issues/2)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no debugger agent for Python 3.  We'll be looking into supporting Python 3 later this year.